# Excel VBA Macro - Out of Memory Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble when running a macro whereby I get an error, usually at the end, stating that it "Out of memory". 
I've looked over a number of posts and followed recommendations to clear any variables and ensure that the code is "cleaner". However, the error still persists.
I have included the code below, any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

A summary of the purpose:
User clicks a button in a template (which is where the code resides)
Macro 1 cleans up the data that the user pastes into a template page.
A userform will appear after macro 1 which the user must input some data - customer name, contract numbers, etc.

Macro 2 runs when the userform button is submitted which creates a new workbook containing all the data from the template (formatted in macro1) and the data from the form. 
It then formats the data for printing with a logo, etc.

**Macro 1**

```
Private Sub ContractsClean()
Application.Visible = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Paste").Name = "Data"

Sheets("Data").Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.Delete

Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Clean the codes
For x = lastrow To 2 Step -1
If Len(Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 1)) > 9 Then
Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 1).Value = Right(Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 1).Value, 9)
End If
Next x

'Add the leading zero
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A:A").Select
Dim Rng As Range
Dim bChanged As Boolean
Dim icol As Long

Dim sString As String
Dim iWSs As Long
iWSs = Workbooks.Count

If iWSs >= 1 Then
    icol = Selection.Column
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each Rng In Selection
        If TypeName(Rng.Value) = "Double" Then
            If Left(Rng.Value, 1) = "9" Then
                Rng = "'0" & Rng.Value
                bChanged = True
            End If
        End If
        If TypeName(Rng.Value) = "String" Then
            If Left(Rng.Value, 3) = "09-" Then
                sString = Rng.Value
                sString = "'" & Replace(sString, "-", "")
                Rng.Value = sString
                bChanged = True
            End If
        End If
        If Rng.Errors(xlNumberAsText).Value = True And bChanged = True Then Rng.Errors(xlNumberAsText).Ignore = True
        If Rng.Row = lastrow Then Exit For
    Next Rng
End If

If iWSs >= 1 Then
    icol = Selection.Column
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each Rng In Selection
        If TypeName(Rng.Value) = "Double" Then
            If Left(Rng.Value, 1) = "8" Then
                Rng = "'0" & Rng.Value
                bChanged = True
            End If
        End If
        If TypeName(Rng.Value) = "String" Then
            If Left(Rng.Value, 3) = "08-" Then
                sString = Rng.Value
                sString = "'" & Replace(sString, "-", "")
                Rng.Value = sString
                bChanged = True
            End If
        End If
        If Rng.Errors(xlNumberAsText).Value = True And bChanged = True Then Rng.Errors(xlNumberAsText).Ignore = True
        If Rng.Row = lastrow Then Exit For
    Next Rng
End If

Rng = Empty
bChanged = Empty
icol = Empty
sString = Empty
iWSs = Empty

Sheets("Data").Columns("B").EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Data").Range("C1").Value = "Quantity"
Sheets("Data").Columns("D").EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Data").Columns("E").EntireColumn.Delete

Sheets("Data").Range("E:F").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Data")

ws.Range("A:B").Locked = False
ws.Range("C:D").Locked = True
ws.Range("E:F").Locked = False
ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, Password:="Sanchez7"

'Completion message box
Dim Answer As String
Dim MyNote As String

    'Place your text here
    MyNote = "Cleanse complete. Do you want to create a local price agreement?"

    'Display MessageBox
    Answer = MsgBox(MyNote, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Action")

    If Answer = vbNo Then
        'Code for No button Press
    Else
        'Code for Yes button Press
        ProposalForm.Show
    End If

Answer = Empty
MyNote = Empty
lastrow = Empty

End Sub
```

**Form Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sBuyGroup As String, sLPA As String, sRep As String, sStart As Date, sEnd As Date, sCurrency As String
Dim bExit As Boolean, sSort As String

    sBuyGroup = txt_BuyGroup.Text
    sLPA = txt_LPA.Text
    sRep = txt_Rep.Text
    sStart = txt_Start.Text
    sEnd = txt_End.Text
    sCurrency = ComboBox1.Value

    If sBuyGroup = "" Then
        bExit = True
        MsgBox ("The account number cannot be blank")
    End If

    If sLPA = "" And bExit = False Then
        bExit = True
        MsgBox ("The carriage option cannot be blank")
    End If

    If sRep = "" And bExit = False Then
        bExit = True
        MsgBox ("The discount option cannot be blank")
    End If

    If bExit = False Then
        Call CreateProposal(sBuyGroup, sLPA, sRep, sStart, sEnd, sCurrency)
        Unload Me
        Else
    End If

    sBuyGroup = Empty
    sLPA = Empty
    sRep = Empty
    sStart = Empty
    sEnd = Empty
    sCurrency = Empty

End Sub
```

**Macro 3 (which I believe is what causes the error)**

```
Sub CreateProposal(sBuyGroup As String, sLPA As String, sRep As String, sStart As Date, sEnd As Date, sCurrency As String)
Dim picLogo As Picture
Set picLogo = Sheets("Info").Pictures("PH_LOGO")


'Copy data from original workbook
Dim exApp As Excel.Application
Set exApp = GetExcelObject()
exApp.Visible = True
Dim OGWB As Workbook
Set OGWB = ActiveWorkbook
OGWB.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:F15000").Copy
Dim wbProposal As Workbook
Set wbProposal = exApp.Workbooks.Add
wbProposal.Activate
wbProposal.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbProposal.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Raw"
exApp.CutCopyMode = False
exApp.Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Copy the logo so we can close original workbook
wbProposal.Sheets.Add
wbProposal.Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "LPA"
OGWB.Sheets("Info").Pictures("PH_LOGO").Cut
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Paste
Selection.Name = "PH_LOGO"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Pictures("PH_LOGO").Left = 20
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Pictures("PH_LOGO").Top = 13
'wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Pictures("PH_LOGO").Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(5.51)
'wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Pictures("PH_LOGO").Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.64)
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("A1").Select
Set picLogo = Nothing
exApp.CutCopyMode = False

wbProposal.Activate
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Select

'Set BG to all white
    With wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Cells.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

'Add contact header
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("D2").Value = "performancehealth.co.uk"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("D3").Value = "Main: +44 (0) 3448 730 035"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("D4").Value = "Fax: +44 (0) 1623 557 769"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("G2").Value = "Nunn Brook Road, Huthwaite,"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("G3").Value = "Sutton-in-Ashfield"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("G4").Value = "Nottinghamshire, NG17 2HU, UK"

    With wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("D2").Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Bold = True
    End With

    With wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("D3:D4,G2:G4").Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0.499984740745262
    End With

wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("G6").Value = "Local Price Agreement"

    With wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("G6").Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Bold = True
        .Size = 14
    End With

'Arrange Column widths
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 2.5
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 13
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("B14").Value = "Item Code"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 41.5
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("C14").Value = "Item Description"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Columns("D:F").ColumnWidth = 12
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("D14").Value = "Sale UOM"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("E14").Value = "Min Qty"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("F14").Value = "Rate"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Columns("G:H").ColumnWidth = 13.5
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("G14").Value = "Start Date"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("H14").Value = "Expiry Date"

wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("B14:H14").Font.Bold = True
With wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("B14:H14").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

'Fill out details from form
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("B8").Value = "Buying Group:"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("B10").Value = "Sales Rep:"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("B11").Value = "Currency:"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("E8").Value = "LPA Number:"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("E10").Value = "Start Date:"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("E11").Value = "Expiry Date:"
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("B8:B11").Font.Bold = True
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("E8:E11").Font.Bold = True

wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("C8").Value = sBuyGroup
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("C10").Value = sRep
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("C11").Value = sCurrency
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("F8").Value = sLPA
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("F10").Value = sStart
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("F11").Value = sEnd

sBuyGroup = Empty
sRep = Empty
sCurrency = Empty
sLPA = Empty
sStart = Empty
sEnd = Empty

'Import the list
Dim lastrow As Long
wbProposal.Sheets("Raw").Select
lastrow = wbProposal.Sheets("Raw").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
wbProposal.Sheets("Raw").Columns("C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
wbProposal.Sheets("Raw").Range("F:G").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
wbProposal.Sheets("Raw").Range("E" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"
wbProposal.Sheets("Raw").Range("A2:G" & lastrow).Copy
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Select
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
exApp.CutCopyMode = False

'Setup print area
lastrow = wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("F15:F" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"

wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$H$" & lastrow
With wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$14:$14"
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 100
End With

'Redo the picture size (changes during column amendments
'wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Pictures("PH_LOGO").Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(5.51)
'wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Pictures("PH_LOGO").Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.64)

lastrow = Empty
exApp.DisplayAlerts = False
exApp.CutCopyMode = False
wbProposal.Sheets("LPA").Range("A1").Select
wbProposal.Sheets("Raw").Delete
exApp.DisplayAlerts = False
exApp.ScreenUpdating = True
OGWB.Close False

Set OGWB = Nothing
Set wbProposal = Nothing
Set exApp = Nothing


Application.Quit

End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Return an intance of Excel
' First tries to open an existing instance. If it fails, it will create an instance.
' If that fails too, then we return 'Nothing'
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function GetExcelObject() As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim xlo As Object
    ' Try to get running instance of Excel
    Set xlo = GetObject("Excel.Application")
    If xlo Is Nothing Then
        Set xlo = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Set GetExcelObject = xlo
End Function
```

Comment: Just a note (no solution): If you declare `lastrow As Long` it doesn't make any sense to declare `Dim x As Integer` If you use it in `For x = lastrow To 2 Step -1`. In general I recommend never to use `Integer` and always to use `Long` instead (especially when dealing with row counts because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle). Also there is no advantage in using `Integer` because it needs the same space in memory as `Long` does unless you use a 16bit system. You will only need `Integer` when communicating with old APIs.

Comment: Another note: Don't use `Object.Select` then `Selection.Activity`. Use `Object.Activity` in the first place, unless you want the object to be selected at the end of the process.

Comment: If you run out of memory this could be because there is just not enough memory in your system, or it is occupied by other applications, or you need more than a 32 bit Excel can use, there is a limit of 2 GB (then using the 64 bit Office can help). Maybe you can add to your question something about your system configuration and which Office version/edition you use.

Comment: Does it manage to do some part of macro, then stops, or nothing happens? `OGWB.Sheets("Data").Cells.Copy` drew my attention. Maybe it's too much for your Excel/machine? Can you copy just significant part of this sheet?

Comment: Thanks for comments. @Peh, I will remove the integers (useful info!). dadler, I also make those changes. brainac, let me try this now and I'll see if it makes a difference. The macro does run to the end but shows the error just before completion and Excel sometimes stops responding or lets me press OK. I did notice that if I check task manager, there are two instances of EXCEL.exe *32 running

Comment: Is there a reason why you decided to use that `GetExcelObject` instead of just using the current instance of Excel? That looks unnecessary complicated to me and probably that is the issue why you got 2 instances in your task manager. Instead of another instance you could just use the current instance and add a new workbook there like: `Application.Workbooks.Add` I think that would take less memory too. Don't forget to [edit] the question and update it to your current code for further questions.

Comment: @Peh, Yes, I wanted it to use the existing instance of Excel but when I run through that function, I can see each time it sees "xlo" as nothing and creates a new object (Excel.Application"). *Updated code now

Comment: @jamesc100 I mean you don't need this function at all. Remove it (`GetExcelObject`) completely and get it done without it. The current instance is always accessible with `Application`. Also go and find a tutorial on "*how to avoid `.Select`, `Selection.` and `.Activate`*" (there are a lot on Google). This will make your code much faster if you don't use these 3. Also specify a worksheet for **every** `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` etc. like `Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheetname")` and then use `ws.Cells` or `ws.Range` otherwise VBA guesses which sheet you mean.

Comment: Thanks @Peh, appreciate the pointers. I've removed the GetExcelObject and the macro has worked without the error and no duplicate instance of Excel running afterwards. I'll clean up the code as you've recommended before I finish this up, thanks again!